# CommandBar overflow menu not detecting taps

Tags: c#, uwp, commandbar

I have a CommandBar. The main part works, including detecting taps. The overflow menu shows the tab names, but when I tap one of the tabs, nothing happens, and I can't see that any code fires. What am I missing?

```
<Page
        x:Class="Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="using:System"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="TabBar">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>
    <Grid Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PageGrid">
        <local:WindowsAdAndContentWrapperView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ContentView"></local:WindowsAdAndContentWrapperView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Command bar setup code that fires not long after app launch. There are a lot of tabs, so some of them get pushed into the overflow menu. The ones that remain in the primary menu work fine.

```
static class WindowsTabContextAdditions
{
  public static void SetupWindowsCommandBar(this TabContext context, CommandBar bar)
  {
    // TabContext and Tab are both my custom classes.
    foreach (Tab tab in context.Tabs)
    {
      AppBarButton button = new AppBarButton();
      IconElement icon = IconElements.ForTab(tab);
      button.Label = tab.DisplayString;
      button.Icon = icon;
      bar.PrimaryCommands.Add(button);
    }
  }
}

static class IconElements
{
  public const string IconPathPrefix = @"ms-appx:///Images/";
  public static IconElement ForTab(Tab tab)
  {
    BitmapIcon r = null;
    string name = tab.WindowsBitmapName();
    string path = IconPathPrefix + name + ".png";
    r = new TabBitmapIcon(tab);
    r.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    r.Tapped += Icon_Tapped;     
    return r;
  }


  private static void Icon_Tapped(Object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // This method fires when the tab is selected. For the non-overflow ones, it works.
    MyDebuggingClass.WriteLine("Tap detected!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the SecondaryCommands collection can contain only AppBarButton, AppBarToggleButton, or AppBarSeparator command elements. Icons are by default not shown in it.

Source from MSDN document [CommandBar.SecondaryCommands property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.secondarycommands)

So if the Icon wasn't shown, it wouldn't fire the Tap event.If you want to fire Tap event, you need to make Icon show first.

I followed DamirArh's suggestion in this thread [Show icon on SecondaryCommands (UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185245/show-icon-on-secondarycommands-uwp) to make the SecondaryCommands show the Icons. Then I registered Tap event for BitmapIcon. It worked well. When I clicked Icon, the Tap event will be fired.

You can refer to my code for reference:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="68" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowContentRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Margin="0,14,0,4" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="2,0,2,6" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="OverflowContentRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="OverflowContent" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Margin="0,14,0,4" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0,12,0" Padding="0,5,0,7" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextTrimming="Clip" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="TabBar">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/StoreLogo.png" Tapped="Icon_Tapped"></BitmapIcon>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Comment: This is a correct answer to the question as stated -- but the actual situation was more absurd than that, and your answer pointed it out to me. What I really needed to do was add the tap event to the button, not the icon. Duh.